# Как сделать скролл, чтобы он не занимал место в блоке

Tags: html, flexbox

Проходил тестовое задание на вакансию html-верстальщика. 
Дали следующее задание

> Суть тестового в верстке виджета ордер-бук в виде таблицы. Виджет
>   должен меняться в ширине от 900 до 1920 пкс.
>
> Таблица скроллится внутри (оба столбца скроллятся одновременно), шапка
>   остается на месте. Полоса скролл-бара начинается под шапкой. При
>   скролле значения в таблице не должны наезжать на шапку. В таблице
>   должен быть только один скролл-бар.
>
> Строки в таблице должны менять цвет фона при хавере (немного
>   затемняться), независимо: отдельно левая сторона, отдельно правая.
>
> Необходимо реализовать таблицу чистой версткой без js. Без библиотек,
>   сторонних ресетов. Код должен быть чистый и понятный, возможно
>   использование препроцессоров.
>
> Внешний вид должен соответствовать макету (блок виджета, тени и т.д.
>   обязательны).

Дали 5 часов. Я сначала на таблицах начал верстать, потом понял, что не выйдет с таблицами как надо сделать, пока с флекс-боксами разбирался, пока перебирал структуру, почти все время вышло. По факту выполнил все, только скролл у меня не получился. Средняя линия таблицы сдвигается на ширину скролла, так с этим и не разобрался.

В итоге сказали что по в принципе не критично, но БЭМ хромает, и все-таки качество кода неприемлимо, чтобы получить вакантное место. Ну получил обратную связь, буду заполнять пробелы. А вопрос про скролл так меня и мучает, самому уже интересно стало.

Может кто подсказать в чем ошибка? Как сделать скролл, чтобы он не сдвигал таблицу. Сам пока не нашел решения

```css
body {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;    
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

.order-book {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;    
    min-width: 900px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    height: 640px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 20px;
}

.order-book__header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.order-book__header__title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.order-book__header__title::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 7px;    
    background: url('img/arrow.png') no-repeat;
}

.order-book__header__buttons input {    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.order-book__header__buttons__reference {
    background: url('img/buttons.png')
}

.order-book__header__buttons__settings {
    background: url('img/buttons.png') 20px;
}

.order-book__table {    
    height: 560px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.block-static, .block-scroll {
    display: flex;
} 




.block_position_left, .block_position_right  {
    width: 50%;        
    height: 100%;
}
 .block_position_left {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.order-book__table__header {    
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    font-weight: bold;
    justify-content: space-between
}

.order-book__table__header span {
    display: block;    
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
}

.order-book__table__header span:first-child,
.order-book__table__content__row span:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}

.order-book__table__header span:last-child,
.order-book__table__content__row span:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}

.order-book__table__content {
    width: 100%;    
    
}

.order-book__table__content__row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;    
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    color: #666;
}

.order-book__table__content__row span {
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

.order-book__table__content__row:hover {
    background: #ebeef9;
    color: #000;
}

.test1 {
    position: relative;    
    height: 521px;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    /* padding-right: 10px; */
}

.block-scroll {
    max-height: 521px;
    width: calc(100% + 10px);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.block-scroll:hover {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: calc(100% + 7px);
    position: absolute;
    left: 3px;
}

.block-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 3px;     
}

 .block-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    background: #79817f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="widspan=device-widspan, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Тестовое задание - Кошелек.ру</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="order-book">
        <div class="order-book__header">
            <h1 class="order-book__header__title">Order Book</h1>
            <div class="order-book__header__buttons">
                <input class="order-book__header__buttons__reference" type="button" value="">
                <input class="order-book__header__buttons__settings" type="button" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="order-book__table">
            <div class="block-static">
                <div class="block_position_left">
                    <div class="order-book__table__header">
                        <span>Count</span>
                        <span>Total</span>
                        <span>Amount</span>
                        <span>Price</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block_position_right">
                    <div class="order-book__table__header">
                        <span>Price</span>
                        <span>Amount</span>
                        <span>Total</span>
                        <span>Count</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="test1">
                <div class="block-scroll">
                    <div class="block_position_left">
                        <div class="order-book__table__content">
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>11</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>286.780</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="block_position_right">
                        <div class="order-book__table__content">
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                                <span>286.780</span>
                                <span>53133</span>
                                <span>214729</span>
                                <span>11</span>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>


            


        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий вариант без использования flex (помним о кроссбраузерности и психов юзающих старый ie). Скролл появляется при наведении на нижнюю часть. Хедер закреплен. Плюс данного варианта верстки с использованием таблиц в том что будет правильно копироваться в эксель.

Особенность данного варианта - вынесение скролла из таблицы (можно кстати и оставить внутри, тогда смотрим вариант автора).

суть:

```
- parent (position:relative; width:300px;)
  - scroller (position:absolute; overflow-y:scroll;)
    - child (width: 300px;)
```

Не стал кстати стилизовать скролл и использовать БЭМ, чтобы оставить минимум читабельного кода. (советую смотреть на полном экране, иначе скролла не увидите :D)

```css
.place {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 900px;
}

.place * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table .head {
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.table .head .left,
.table .head .right {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.table .head .left {
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.table .head table {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.table .head table th {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.table .head table th:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

.table .head table th:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

.table .body {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.table .body .scroller {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.table .body .scroller:hover {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.table .body .scroller .content {
  width: 900px;
}

.table .body .left,
.table .body .right {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.table .body .left {
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.table .body table {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.table .body table tr td {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.table .body table tr td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

.table .body table tr td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

.table .body table tr:hover td {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="place">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="head">
      <div class="left">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Count</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Count</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <div class="scroller">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="left">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>11</td>
                  <td>214729</td>
                  <td>53133</td>
                  <td>286.780</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: с бордером поди не получилось бы, по заданию скролл должен появляться только при наведении на нижнюю часть таблицы (:hover) не все задание уместилось в вопрос

Comment: если будет время на досуге попробую поковыряться, задача на самом деле интересная. но боюсь что времени она сожрет дофига)

Comment: Вот я тест провалил получается, а задача самому покоя не дает, тоже пытаюсь найти решение

Comment: @shub1nk все, замутил готовый вариант, скролл вынес за таблицу - мне такое решение показалось самым интересным)

Answer (score 2):

Вот таким образом получилось организовать что-то похожее. Есть небольшое брожение данных в таблице, но оно не значительное, если не прицеплять скролл на событие hover то вполне рабочий вариант получается.

EDIT: Решил еще поиграться со скроллом, теперь получился такой вариант, как по заданию, прикладываю код целиком. 
Правда кроссбраузерность страдает:
- Opera, Yandex, Chrome - все отлично, 
- IE11 версии походу не понимает такой формат `width: calc(100% + 10px)` - но хотя бы таблица нормально отображается, косяк только при наведении,
- в Safari вообще какой-то треш - вся таблица рассыпалась

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.order-book {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  min-width: 900px;
  max-width: 1920px;
  height: 640px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 20px;
}

.order-book__header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.order-book__header__title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.order-book__header__title::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 7px;
  background: url('img/arrow.png') no-repeat;
}

.order-book__header__buttons input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.order-book__header__buttons__reference {
  background: url('img/buttons.png')
}

.order-book__header__buttons__settings {
  background: url('img/buttons.png') 20px;
}

.order-book__table {
  height: 560px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.block-static,
.block-scroll {
  display: flex;
}

.block_position_left,
.block_position_right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block_position_left {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.order-book__table__header {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.order-book__table__header span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}

.order-book__table__header span:first-child,
.order-book__table__content__row span:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

.order-book__table__header span:last-child,
.order-book__table__content__row span:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}

.order-book__table__content {
  width: 100%;
}

.order-book__table__content__row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  color: #666;
}

.order-book__table__content__row span {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.order-book__table__content__row:hover {
  background: #ebeef9;
  color: #000;
}

.block-scroll-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 521px;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.block-scroll {
  max-height: 521px;
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.block-scroll:hover {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: calc(100% + 13px);
}

.block-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
}

.block-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #79817f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="widspan=device-widspan, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
  <title>Тестовое задание - Кошелек.ру</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="order-book">
    <div class="order-book__header">
      <h1 class="order-book__header__title">Order Book</h1>
      <div class="order-book__header__buttons">
        <input class="order-book__header__buttons__reference" type="button" value="">
        <input class="order-book__header__buttons__settings" type="button" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="order-book__table">
      <div class="block-static">
        <div class="block_position_left">
          <div class="order-book__table__header">
            <span>Count</span>
            <span>Total</span>
            <span>Amount</span>
            <span>Price</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block_position_right">
          <div class="order-book__table__header">
            <span>Price</span>
            <span>Amount</span>
            <span>Total</span>
            <span>Count</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="block-scroll-wrapper">
        <div class="block-scroll">
          <div class="block_position_left">
            <div class="order-book__table__content">
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>11</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>286.780</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="block_position_right">
            <div class="order-book__table__content">
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>
              <div class="order-book__table__content__row">
                <span>286.780</span>
                <span>53133</span>
                <span>214729</span>
                <span>11</span>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>





    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: скинь плиз целиком, чтобы можно было запустить. у меня тоже получился один очень интересный вариант, сейчас допилю его и покажу.

Comment: @DenisRoss, Приложил все исходники. Можно сказать, что решение все-таки нашел, но 2 браузера пострадали

Comment: да, мне твой вариант нравится, единственным нюансом я бы посчитал скролл внутри - если попадется браузер без поддержки вебкитов, то стилизация скрола слетит и он превратиться в стандартный 17-ти пиксельный, и тогда будет наезжать на данные, если не сделать соответствующего отступа, но в целом это можно вполне предусмотреть) хорошую ты задачку подкинул)

Answer (score 0):

А подобный вариант не устраивает?

```css
.table {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto hidden;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  position: relative;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.grid.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #ddd;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}



.item {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.grid.header .item:not(:last-child) {
  width: calc(100% - 11px);
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="grid header">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid content">
    <div class="item">Value 1</div>
    <div class="item">Value 2</div>
    <div class="item">Value 3</div>
    <div class="item">Value 4</div>
    
    <div class="item">Value 1</div>
    <div class="item">Value 2</div>
    <div class="item">Value 3</div>
    <div class="item">Value 4</div>
    
    <div class="item">Value 1</div>
    <div class="item">Value 2</div>
    <div class="item">Value 3</div>
    <div class="item">Value 4</div>
    
    <div class="item">Value 1</div>
    <div class="item">Value 2</div>
    <div class="item">Value 3</div>
    <div class="item">Value 4</div>
    
    <div class="item">Value 1</div>
    <div class="item">Value 2</div>
    <div class="item">Value 3</div>
    <div class="item">Value 4</div>
    
    <div class="item">Value 1</div>
    <div class="item">Value 2</div>
    <div class="item">Value 3</div>
    <div class="item">Value 4</div>
    
    <div class="item">Value 1</div>
    <div class="item">Value 2</div>
    <div class="item">Value 3</div>
    <div class="item">Value 4</div>
    
    <div class="item">Value 1</div>
    <div class="item">Value 2</div>
    <div class="item">Value 3</div>
    <div class="item">Value 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Немного взял от вашего примера и добавил width: calc(100% + 3px). Получается теперь лучше, но скролл снаружи блока, а хотелось бы изнутри его сделать, как здесь https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dHMFkXuheKt8SZK6S6f2OISnQewHdLWGGf6w3XMI1Bs

Comment: @shub1nk, нету доступа к документу..)

Comment: Расшарил документ https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dHMFkXuheKt8SZK6S6f2OISnQewHdLWGGf6w3XMI1Bs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @shub1nk, насколько я знаю, это сложно реализовать только из-за того, что у каждого браузера и\или OS свой скролл. В данном случае нам нужно только узнать ширину его, но даже это сложно)

Comment: @CblPoK2513, в принципе в задании оговаривалась только последняя версия Хрома. В ней проверяли. А ширина и стили тоже не важны, главное, как я понял, чтобы внутри был... Хотя все это так туманно описано, что может даже и не стоило заморачиваться, главное чтобы не разъезжался макет и все. Из задания: `Скролл-бар в таблице должен появляться по хаверу на таблицу, сама таблица и виджет должны оставаться на месте. Внешний вид скроллбара не принципиален.
`

Comment: @shub1nk, где-то читал про то, как создают кастомные скролл бары с нуля. Там говорили, что скроллы везде не больше, вроде, `20px`, сейчас попробую что-нибудь придумать.

Comment: @shub1nk, увы.. сделать появление скролл бара при наведение нормально не могу, чёт идей нету)

Comment: @CblPoK2513, Ну теперь хотя бы скролл появляется и не разваливает таблицу, уже неплохо - тоже результат) может позже попадется какое-нибудь решение